# use Raspberry Pi as a bridge b/w mobile and router

Tags: raspberry-pi

How to use Raspberry Pi as a bridge b/w USB Tethered mobile phone and Router, using "ethernet cable b/w Raspberry Pi and router" and "USB cable b/w mobile phone and Raspberry pi"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a better fit on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

To do so you need to create a software bridge b/w "usb0"(usb interface) and "eth0"(ethernet interface) on raspberry-pi. You need to take following steps:

Connect your android phone and raspberry-pi using USB cable and Turn on "USB-Tethering" from your phone.
Your raspberry-pi should be recieving internet connection.
Connect raspberry-pi to router using ethernet cable.
Enable "dhcp" on the router.

Now type the following commands on your bash terminal.

```
 sudo brctl addbr usb2eth
 sudo brctl addif usb2eth eth0
 sudo brctl addif usb2eth usb0
 sudo brctl stp usb2eth on
 sudo ifconfig usb2eth up
```

after waiting for at most two minutes internet on your router should be up and running. Now you should be able to access the internet over wifi through router.

Note:
you can install brctl using  "sudo apt-get install bridge-utils"

Comment: Thank you for this!  These were the details I needed to tether my mobile device to my home network: https://dltj.org/article/ubiquity-tethered-iphone/

Comment: works like CHARM , but is this secure ? . Will a Software bridge end up exposing LAN to the outside world via the mobile internet

Comment: @PeterMurray I am using an android device, The PI immediately sees it , no issue, I skipped a lot of the steps and it works fine.  How can I tether another android phone (with another LTE 4G mobile internet). combine the 2 internets and use ?